# Нарисовать равносторонний многоугольник в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, математика, графика, любой-язык

Есть canvas (js), на нем нужно нарисовать равносторонний многоугольник со случайным количеством вершин. Как определить координаты точек, зная координаты начальной точки и расстояние от нее до точек?

Работающий код:

```
function drawPoligon(x0, y0, n) {
    console.log('x0=' + x0 + ', y0=' + y0 + ', n=' + n + ', r=' + r);
    var coordArray = [[]];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var xi = x0 + r * Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/n);
        var yi = y0 + r * Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/n);
        console.log('i=' + i + ', xi=' + xi + ', yi=' + yi);
        coordArray[i] = [xi, yi];
    }
    console.log(coordArray);
    return coordArray;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не sign а sin...

Comment: @MBo  спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно еще угол одной из точек. Считаем его нулевым для простоты. Координаты центральной точки - *x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>0</sub>, радиус описанной окружности - *R*, число сторон - *N*... *i* меняется от 0 до *N*-1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так получим **правильный** многоугольник. У вас, правда, слово другое - равносторонний... Но тогда для 4 точек вам годится и квадрат, и ромб? Или все же - правильный?

Comment: Да даже не знаю :) Они же самоочевидны... Все вершины правильного многоугольника просто находятся под равным углом одна от другой, а все N углов - полная окружность, 2*pi. Ну и смещение относительно начала координат.

Comment: @mirypoko они называются "математика из курса средней школы"

Answer (score 1):

Координаты точек определяются по формуле из предыдущего ответа, которое напоминает параметрическое уравнение окружности с радиусом `R` и центром `center`. А `N` это количество сторон многоугольника.

Реализация:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext('2d');
    var id = 0;
    var Point2d = function(x, y) {
      this.x = x || 0;
      this.y = y || 0;
    }

    Point2d.prototype.set = function(x, y) { 
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    };

    Point2d.prototype.translate = function(p) { 
      this.x += p.x;
      this.y += p.y;
      return this;
    };

    function getRegularPolygonPoints(center, N, R) {
      var points = [];
      var alpha = 2*Math.PI / N;  
      for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        points.push(new Point2d( 
          center.x + R*Math.cos(alpha*i),
          center.y + R*Math.sin(alpha*i))
        )
      }  
      return points;
    }


    function drawPolygon(points) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y); 
      for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
      }
      ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);//  close the shape
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#899";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    var center = new Point2d(250, 120);
    var regPolPoints = getRegularPolygonPoints(center, 4, 50);

    var render = function() {    
      drawPolygon(regPolPoints);
      id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
    <canvas id="cnv" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Будут вопросы задавайте